# Closures in Loop not responding to the usual maneuvers

Tags: javascript

At first blush, this looks like the same old 'closures in a loop' problem, but applying my usual solution is not actually solving the problem.  Here's the code:

```
G.MultiToggle = function(each){
    //data takes the form
    //[{"data":(see Toggle), "onOpen":function(){}, "onClosed":function(){}},...]
    this.children = [];
    var which = null;
    var toggles = [];
    var that = this;
    function makeOpenFn(j){
        var info = each[j];
        console.log(j);
        return function(){
            console.log(j);
            info["onOpen"]();
            if(which!=null){
                toggles[which].close_up();
            }
            which = j;
        };
    };
    function makeClosedFn(j){
        var info = each[j];
        console.log(j);
        return function(){
            console.log(j);
            info["onClosed"]();
            which = null;
        };
    };
    function makeToggler(obj,opener,closer) {
        return new G.Toggle(
           obj.data,
           opener,
           closer
        );
    };
    for(var i=0; i<each.length; i++){
        var openFn = makeOpenFn(i);
        var closedFn = makeClosedFn(i);
        toggles[i] = makeToggler(each[i],openFn,closedFn);
        toggles[i].close_up();
        that.addChild(toggles[i]);
    }
    console.log(toggles);
}
G.MultiToggle.prototype = new createjs.Container();
```

The openFn and closedFn are used as event handlers by the toggle object later on.  When they're invoked, they all spit out the results from i=2.  I've tried moving the info variable declaration into the inner functions, and many other gymnastic permutations.  I'm pulling my hair out, over here.  Any help would be appreciated.
EDIT: Added more of the surrounding code for context.

Comment: What is the `this` of `this.children()` or `that = this`? What is `each`? What are the expected semantics of `which`? Why do you expect the `which` referred to in your functions to have anything other than the latest global value when your function is eventually executed?

Comment: it is still a closure inside a function problem because you are using the loop scoped values `openFn` & `closedFn` inside a function inside the loop

Comment: This is all happening within the constructor of an easel.js Container (so that's what 'this' refers to).  I don't expect 'which' to have anything other than the global value.  The point of 'which' is to retain whichever toggle is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the old closure in a loop problem. Only, you've missed a variable:

```
for(var i=0; i<each.length; i++){
    openFn = makeOpenFn(i); //------ looks OK
    closedFn = makeClosedFn(i); //-- looks OK
    toggles[i] = function(){
        return new G.Toggle(
           each[i].data, //--------- AHA! closure in a loop!
           openFn,
           closedFn
        );
    }();
    toggles[i].close_up();
    that.addChild(toggles[i]);
}
```

You just need to break the closure to **that** `i` as well:

```
    toggles[i] = function(new_i){
        return new G.Toggle(
           each[new_i].data,
           openFn,
           closedFn
        );
    }(i);
```

Or, if you prefer the style of the other functions:

```
function makeToggler(obj,opener,closer) {
    return new G.Toggle(
       obj.data,
       opener,
       closer
    );
}

for(var i=0; i<each.length; i++){
    openFn = makeOpenFn(i); //------ looks OK
    closedFn = makeClosedFn(i); //-- looks OK
    toggles[i] = makeToggler(each[i],openFn,closedFn);
    toggles[i].close_up();
    that.addChild(toggles[i]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry - that still hasn't done it.  I've put in both versions, and it's still behaving as if i==2 :(

Comment: Are you sure? I'm sure it works. Do you have a reproducible jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

If you think there is problem inside the loop, I'll show you that the problem is not from your loop.

Let's make a simple loop that same as your loop to proof it:

```js
function my(a){
  return a+3;
}

for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
  var ab = my(i);
  var aa = function(){
    alert(ab);
    alert(i);
  }();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't do the trick.  It's still behaving as if 'openFn' thinks i is 2.

Comment: The only reason the first code didn't work is because you didn't pass in the i at the end of `...)()`. It should be `...)(i)` and to avoid confusion the function should have used another variable: `(function(j){...` then do `alert(j)` because you've now passed `i` into `j`

Comment: I've edited my answer, my previous answer doesn't work because I forgot `...)()` at the end of the function `})()`.